# How to create div with 100% height in dynamic table-cell?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, opera

I have dynamic and static table-cell. I need create div with 100% height in dynamic table-cell.

I have minimal solution - this work only in Chrome & Firefox. In Opera & IE child div has a top table size. Is there a solution for opera and ie without js?

Good:

[image: good]

Bad:

[image]

---

**update #1** For Chrome, FF and Opera (*Presto*):

```
<table class='m-table'>
    <tr>
      <td class='m-top-cell'>
        <div class="b-subtable">
          <div class="b-content"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='m-bottom-cell'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

.m-table {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.m-top-cell {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;

  background-color: red;
}

.m-bottom-cell {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 200px;
}

.b-subtable {
  background-color: #E76D13;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .m-top-cell {
      padding: 5px;
  }

  .b-subtable {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .b-subtable:after {
    content: '. .';
    display: block;
    word-spacing: 99in;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    font-size: 0.13em;
    line-height: 0;
  }
}

.b-content {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;

  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "In Opera & IE child div has a top table size." ?

Comment: Is there a reason you MUST use table cells?  Tables are not recommended for layouts and, often, I've just used divs for table structures.  What is the scenario you're describing?  Also, I am too confused as to what you mean by "In Opera & IE child div has a top table size"

Comment: @GrahamRobertson There are 3 table cells, located in the column. The top and bottom of the cell have a fixed size and pinned to the top and bottom of the unit. The central cell is dimensionless. Inside it is a block of an even larger, but the size should not be considered a cell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.m-top-cell{    
    /* other css properties */
    /*remove height:100% */ 
    position:relative;

}

.b-subtable{
    /* other css properties */
    /* remove height: 100% and display: table */
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

---

And also check your `link` tag notation,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: In HTML5 `type="text/css"` is default value. It is not necessary to write. Your solution not work in FF and IE - `position:relative;` for table-cell not work.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters Did you remove `height:100%` and other properties as I suggested in my post?